# Laravel 5.2 database transaction

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I've looked up the offcial document and googled, but haven't get a clear answer.
Does laravel's transaction work well on both Innodb and Myisam?

I know MyISAM doesn't support transactions. I just wondering if Laravel has some amazing function to do this, like delete records or update back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use MySQL. Laravel doesn't support transactions in MyISAM because MyISAM engine doesn't support transactions, so it's obvious Laravel cannot change database behaviour. You should use InnoDB if you want to use transactions.

Comment: I'd go one further and say you shouldn't use MyISAM unless you have no other option. It's a dangerously brittle database engine that's much harder to tune than InnoDB.

Comment: I know MyISAM doesn't support transactions. I just wondering if Laravel has some amazing function to do this, like delete records or update back.

I use opencart, and its still MyISAM... I'm thinking to use its database, rewrite with laravel...

Comment: @user3562689 You can change Myisam tables to InnoDB without a problem